# Хранение файлов в mongoDb либо лучше на hdd диске?

Tags: mongodb

Имеет ли смысл хранить временные файлы размером 0.2-5 mb в базе данных mongo?
Скажем генерируется отчёт excel и помещается в БД, либо кладётся на диск.
Затем пользователь его скачивает и он удаляется. 
Либо работа с диском будет быстрее?